# Python descriptors

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

From the [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) docs:

> A descriptor can be called directly by its method name. For example, `d.__get__(obj)`.

What would be an example of this with the following class?

```
class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, color="red"):
        self.color = color
```

For example, what is `d` and what is `obj`? How would `"d.__get__(obj)"` be called with the above class/instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Working Example

To make your example a descriptor, it needs to have a [*__get__()*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__get__) method:

```
class Descriptor:
    def __init__(self, color="red"):
        self.color = color
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        return obj.size + ' ' + self.color
```

Use that descriptor in another class:

```
class A:
     pair = Descriptor('green')
     def __init__(self, size):
          self.size = size
```

Invoke the descriptor like this:

```
>>> a = A('big')
>>> a.pair
'big green'
```

Hope this working example helps :-)

### Key points

1) A class is a [*descriptor*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__get__#object.__get__) if defines any one of *__get__()*, *__set__()*, or _*_delete__()*.

2) Put it to work by making an instance of the descriptor and storing it as a class variable in another class.

3) Invoke the descriptor with normal attribute lookup using the dot operator.

That's really all there is to it :-)

Comment: Thanks for this answer -- Why do you add in the `objtype=None` in the Descriptor?

Comment: That is the signature for \__get__.  That method can be called with either two or three arguments.  The third argument is usually the type of *obj* but can be *None* or omitted when *obj* is not *None*.  Usually, the third argument is only relevant when the descriptor in invoked from a class rather than an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Descriptors are a way to make code look like data and also to achieve polymorphism.

There's a good example on the page that you linked to, under "Descriptor Example"
I'll copy it here:

```
class RevealAccess(object):
    """A data descriptor that sets and returns values
       normally and prints a message logging their access.
    """

    def __init__(self, initval=None, name='var'):
        self.val = initval
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
        print('Retrieving', self.name)
        return self.val

    def __set__(self, obj, val):
        print('Updating', self.name)
        self.val = val

>>> class MyClass(object):
...     x = RevealAccess(10, 'var "x"')
...     y = 5
...
>>> m = MyClass()
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
10
>>> m.x = 20
Updating var "x"
>>> m.x
Retrieving var "x"
20
>>> m.y
5
```

Do you see how the class MyClass assigns the RevealAccess descriptor to it's x attribute?

In your case, you would need to also need to add a class that uses the descriptor you made.